# How can I originate a call and read DTMF value using asterisk-java?

Tags: java, asterisk, dtmf

I'm developing a java application that should be able to call another party using [Java-Asterisk](http://www.asterisk-java.org) and get a DTMF value from user. I am using `originate` command of AMI and I'm stuck. I can call the other party but the call is ended immediately after answering and returns `success`.
How can I originate a call and read a DTMF value?

Comment: This question is exactly same as you asked 2 day ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472983/read-dtmf-using-asterisk-java . I am sorry, you have read some books to understand answers.

Comment: i believe that i can use AMI's originate function to connect a user to an application but can not figure how. the documentation is very weak. for know i am using call files but i dont like it!

Comment: i have read this book: "Asterisk Cookbook - O´Reilly - Chapter 2 - Call Control ". I have to be able to use originate function

Comment: I am sorry, you have read FULL book to understand dialplan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OriginateAction originateAction = new OriginateAction();
   originateAction.setChannel("SIP/1001");
   originateAction.setContext("from-internal");
   originateAction.setExten("1002");
   originateAction.setCallerId("Server");
   originateAction.setPriority(1);
   originateAction.setTimeout(30000);

   // connect to Asterisk and log in
   managerConnection.login();
   //send the originate action and wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for Asterisk
   // to send a reply
   ManagerResponse response= managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000);
```

The Originate action in the AMI allows you to send a request over a TCP connection for Asterisk to make a call. This is the most popular method for originating calls from custom applications. The example provided in the solution starts by having Asterisk make a new call to `SIP/1001`. If the phone does not answer within 30 seconds, the call will be aborted. If the call is answered, it is connected to extension 1002 in the `from-internal` context in the dialplan. 
After calling 1002 extension all i need to read DTMF is this:

```
public class HelloAgiScript extends BaseAgiScript {
public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel) throws AgiException
{

    // Answer the channel...
    answer();

    // ...say hello and get DTMF data...
    String data = getData("welcome");

    // ...and hangup.
    hangup();
}
```

}

[click here to see the original HelloAgiScript.](http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html)